# Increment of the detect line

Tags: python, text-parsing

I am reading a game move from the site and I want to detect the appearance of a new move and display information about it

```
while True:
    r = requests.get(URL_TEMPLATE)
    soup = bs(r.text, "lxml")
    buffer = soup.text[soup.text.find('1. '):].partition("*")[0]

    print(buffer)
```

I tried to write the value to the buffer and compare it with the new value but it doesn't work well

Comment: Please read [ask] to improve your question and provide a [example]. You should include the URL of your site if possible, e.g. `URL_TEMPLATE = 'https://lichess.org/dtkxPuQf'`. Please [edit] and add  debug-info, the text from `soup.text` (use `print()`) and tell as what you expected as output from `buffer`.

Comment: What "information about [the move]" do you want to display ?

Comment: @hc_dev list of moves and who went

Answer (score -2):

```
while True:
    r = requests.get(URL_TEMPLATE)
    soup = bs(r.text, "lxml")

    main_buffer = soup.text[soup.text.find('1. '):].partition("*")[0]

    while True:
        buffer = bs(requests.get(URL_TEMPLATE).text, 'lxml').text[soup.text.find('1. '):].partition("*")[0]
        if len(main_buffer) < len(buffer):
            main_buffer = buffer
            break

    print(main_buffer)
```

Comment: Users find it difficult to understand code only answers with no explanation. Please consider adding some description explaining what is does and how it solves the problem or add comments in the source code at appropriate places.